# Jquery Angular Submit BTN enabled on change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

guys. I have this peace of code that is making me confuse and I got stuck.

I have a script for a dropdown that gathers data from db when user selects an option. When selected, the fields are filled with data corresponding to each field. The form is validated by angularjs. The button is still disabled even when the fields are filled with data.

index.php js

```
$("#quick_fill").change(function () {

var id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
    url : "php/autofill.php",
    data : {
    "id" : id
    },
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
      console.log(data.fname);
        $("#first").val(data.fname);
        $("#first").removeClass("ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched");
        $("#first").addClass("ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched");
        $("#last").val(data.lname);
        $("#last").removeClass("ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched");
        $("#last").addClass("ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched");
        $("#middle").val(data.mname);
        $("#middle").removeClass("ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched");
        $("#middle").addClass("ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched");
}
    });
});
```

My Question is how will i going to enable the submit button on the form. when there are already filled out.

HTML form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="frm" novalidate="" >

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="coc" value="<?php printf('%03d',$i);?>">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="padding-left:10px;">
          <div class="col-sm-3"><label>Agency Name:</label>
          <span ng-show="frm.branch.$dirty && frm.branch.$error.required" class="label label-danger" style="margin-left:10px;">Please Pick an Agency</span>
          <span ng-show="frm.branch.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success" style="margin-left:10px;"> </span>        
          <div class="col-sm-3"><label>Last Name:</label>
              <span ng-show="frm.last.$dirty && frm.last.$error.required" class="label label-danger" style="margin-left:10px;">This is Required</span>
              <span ng-show="frm.last.$dirty && frm.last.$error.minlength" class="label label-danger" style="margin-left:10px;">Enter Atleast 2 Characters</span>
              <input ng-model="last" ng-minlength="2" name="last" id="last" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required autocomplete="off">
          </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><label>Given Name:</label>
              <span ng-show="frm.first.$dirty && frm.first.$error.required" class="label label-danger" style="margin-left:10px;">This is Required</span>
              <span ng-show="frm.first.$dirty && frm.first.$error.minlength" class="label label-danger" style="margin-left:10px;">Enter Atleast 2 Characters</span>
              <input ng-model="first" ng-minlength="2" name="first" id="first" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" required autocomplete="off">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3"><label>Middle Name:</label>
              <input ng-model="middle" name="middle" id="middle" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Initial" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
        </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
              <button ng-disabled="frm.$invalid" type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-info">&nbsp; Save &nbsp;</button>`
```

Comment: hi the question is how will i going to enable the button? the submit btn.

Comment: is `#quick_fill` outside of angular scope, or it can be written using angular?

Comment: no quick_fill dropdown is separated with the form. meaning i have a two form at the same time inside the angular scope.

Answer (score 0):

It would be problematic if you mix jquery and angular code together - it can go wrong in many cases.

In this particular case, you are just updating the css class of the input fields. The internal representation of the form in angular still think it is invalid - even if you remove all ng-invalid from the fields.

You should try updating the app to use angular way of setting values.

```
$scope.change = function () {
    var id = $scope.selectedId;

    $http({
      url : "php/autofill.php",
      data : {
        "id" : id
      },
      method : "POST"
    }).then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        console.log(data.fname);
        $scope.first = data.fname;
        $scope.frm.first.$setValidity(true);
        $scope.frm.first.$setPristine(false);
        ...
    });
  };
```

(Above code is just for illustration purpose and not tested)

Comment: what will be my selector for the change function? how will i select the quick_fill dropdown select. tnx

Comment: You can refer to the [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) or other guides on how to contruct the select. You can add a `ng-change` in this select to trigger the change function.